# C# Method in base class that returns derived type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to create a method in a base class that would be able to return derived types. It's not necessary that it actually resides in the base class, but I would like to not have to implement the method in all derived classes.

Something like this.

```
public class Error
{
    protected Error() { }

    public string Message { get; protected set; }

    public static Error Because(string msg)
    {
        return new Error() { Message = msg };
    }
}
```

And then I create two derived types:

```
public class MyError : Error
public class OtherError : Error
```

that I'm able to instantiate with `Because` without any further implementation.

I know I'm able to do an implementation like this:

```
public static T Because<T>(string message)
    where T : Error
{
    var error = default(T);
    error.Message = message;

    return error;
}
```

But then I have to specify the type parameter:

```
MyError err = Error.Because<MyError>("My error");
```

or

```
MyError simp = MyError.Because<MyError>("My error");
```

I would like to be able to call it with something like this:

```
MyError myError = MyError.Because("Something went wrong");
OtherError myError = OtherError.Because("Something else went wrong");
```

Comment: static methods are not inherited so if you want them defined in the derived classes then you'll have to implement them there.  Why no do this with constructors instead?

Comment: @juharr I'm definitely able to define my static generic method Because<T> in Error and call it with OtherError.Because<OtherError>("My error") even though I've only implemented it in Error.

Comment: Does none of your derived classes add any new members? Because otherwise you´d need some mechanism to fill those properties from within your base-class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere At the moment I'm just trying something out. But right now that's not the case, no. I want derived classes to be able to return and handle different errors depending on which error occurred.

Comment: What about a factory? Of course, it won´t let you use the exact same syntax you wrote above, but something like `Error.Because<MyError>("Something went whrong")`. As you seem to know the type at compile-time anyway, I can´t see any advantage of the syntax you mentioned. In fact that is what ? OtherError.Because` resolves to anyway, as static members aren´t inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) fits here.

Like:

```
    public abstract class Error<ConcreteError>
        where ConcreteError : Error<ConcreteError>, new()
    {
        protected Error() { }

        public string Message { get; protected set; }

        public static ConcreteError Because(string msg)
        {
            return new ConcreteError() { Message = msg };
        }
    }
    public class MyError : Error<MyError> { }
    public class OtherError : Error<OtherError> { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyError myError = MyError.Because("Something went wrong");
        OtherError myError2 = OtherError.Because("Something else went wrong");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are describing is a return type covariance which is an accepted and championed language feature which will be implemented in one of the next versions of C# language. Currently release is planned for C# 9.0.

For more details, pls have a look at the corresponding `dotnet/csharplang` discussion thread:

[Champion "Covariant Return Types"](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49)

Comment: Sounds like it will be even easier in the future to do this. Thanks for your input. :)